# Add information to the fist dataset using a second one

Tags: r

Let's suppose that I have those 2 datasets:

```
    > a
    id x1 x2 
    1  a  3
    2  b  2
    3  b  1
```

and

```
    > b
    id x1 x2 
    1  c  3
    3     4
```

What I need is: update the dataset **a** using the dataset **b**.

The new **a** should be:

```
    > a
    id x1 x2 
    1  c  3
    2  b  2
    3  b  4
```

I have no about that. May you suggest me any package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- "id x1 x2 
      1  a  3
      2  b  2
      3  b  1"

b <- "id x1 x2 
      1  c  3
      3  NA  4"

a <- read.table(text = a, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
b <- read.table(text = b, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

a %>% 
  full_join(b, by = "id", suffix = c("", ".1")) %>% 
  mutate(x1 = coalesce(x1.1, x1), x2 = coalesce(x2.1, x2)) %>% 
  select(id, x1, x2)
```

Returns:

```
 id x1 x2
1  1  c  3
2  2  b  2
3  3  b  4
```

Comment: It seems that with huge dataset coalesce dosen't work well.
Is this happening because dplyr is a beta package?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work well, do you mean speed?